# Third Party/CrossDomain Access to Heroku

Tags: heroku

I would like to allow third-party/crossdomain access to my Heroku api.  Currently I have an xml file with crossdomain properties in my other websites... how do I open up access on Heroku to other sites?

Maybe the placement of the xml file is the issue... but I have it all redirected in routes so /crossdomain.xml will point to the correct file.. it just is not allowing access currently.